# What is the difference between javax.persistence.metamodel.Map and java.util.Map?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am trying to write a JDO annotated class in GAE and I want to persist a map. The map is supposed to be an entity field that is a collection of entities hashed by Date. (I am not even sure if this is the right approach).

Eclipse's auto-complete provides me with javax.persistence.metamodel.Map and java.util.Map. What is the difference between these two? What is an example of the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is a class from a standard Java library that is supported in GAE, and the other is part of the JPA API (that you're not using).

Comment: Could you please show an example of how it works? A practical sample? Or is this for internal use only?

Comment: A Map is a Map, nothing special there. So just look at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/orm/one_to_many_map.html

Answer (score 1):

Only these collections [1] were allowed in google-app-engine:

- `java.util.ArrayList<...>`
- `java.util.HashSet<...>`
- `java.util.LinkedHashSet<...>`
- `java.util.LinkedList<...>`
- `java.util.List<...>`
- `java.util.Set<...>`
- `java.util.SortedSet<...>`
- `java.util.Stack<...>`
- `java.util.TreeSet<...>`
- `java.util.Vector<...>`
- See first comment below this post!

So I would recommend you to use these classes with the given packages.

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses?hl=de#Collections

Comment: Not quite true actually. Map has been supported for quite some time via JDO/JPA. See http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=264&can=1&q=map&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20FoundIn%20TargetRelease%20Owner%20Summary  and also the request for them to update the docs http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7548&q=map&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Comment: Attention: The last release of the datanucleus-appengine library was in january 2012. So if you use these files, or the files of the appengine-java-sdk, Map is not supported. As they mentioned in the issue, it will be available with 2.0.1 (or you can build it on your own).

Comment: Not exactly (again ;-) ). There was 2.1.1 in Sept 2012 and 2.0.1.1 in Jun 2012. Also 2.1.2 will be out in the next AppEngine SDK very soon I think (since Google have branched it off for building into that). http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/orm/datanucleus-appengine/

Comment: Where can I download these releases (is there a official site)? At http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/downloads/list is only 2.0.0 available. In my appengine-java-sdk (version 1.7.4) lies only a _datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar_ (lib/user/orm/)?? Maybe if you use maven there is a newer version available, but they don't give you the newest version if you download the sdk over their website  https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=de ?!? I hope I'm not on the wrong way again :D .

Comment: appengine SDK has stuff available under "lib/opt/user/datanucleus" (v2.1.1 AFAIK). What it will take for Google to upgrade the default to 2.x I've no idea. You can obviously just grab the jars (datanucleus-appengine, datanucleus-XXX) from the Maven repo I quoted (whether using Maven or not) and put them manually into your SDK.

Comment: Yeah absolutely right. The new releases lie under "/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/". I didn't notice that they are in the _opt_ folder. Thanks a lot DataNucleus :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see from the javadoc of [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [javax.persistence.metamodel.Map](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-jpa/2.0.0-m2/javax/persistence/metamodel/Map.java) which does not seem to exist in the latest API, the metamodel Map seems to be a wrapper over the util Map so that we can use it to get metadata about the util Map.