# Error when externalizing entities with HashMap

Tags: google-app-engine, graniteds

When my flex app tries to get a persisted entity that has at least one HashMap property I get this error: `org.granite.messaging.persistence.ExternalizablePersistentMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map`
From what I searched, I believe that I'm missing some externalizer configuration, whitch is...... ?

This is what I have:

Entity:

```
@Persistent private HashMap<String, String> email;
```

Gas3 Generated EntityBase: (No Tide)

```
private var _email:IMap;
```

granite-config.xml:

```
<externalizers>
    <externalizer type="org.granite.datanucleus.DataNucleusExternalizer">
        <include annotated-with="javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable"/>
    </externalizer>
</externalizers>
```

Comment: Maybe you have an old version (without map support). Read this answer (and all comments!) -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/14215755/1427942 and check if you have the right version of your libs.

Comment: Persistence seems to be working fine, the problem is when I try to send the retrieved entity to my Flex app.

Comment: After a few google searches I changed HashMap to BasicMap. Now I can send single BasicMap objects back and fourth from Java to Flex. But I still get an `ExternalizablePersistentMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map` error.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up using Maps, I can't be stuck for too long.

Everywhere that I was using HashMap or BasicMap was changed to `HashSet<MyCustomMapLikeEntity>`

Better than nothing...